# Xdebug doesn't show changed vars in PhpStorm

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstorm, xdebug

I have Ubuntu 16.04, nginx, PHP 7.2, Xdebug 2.6.

Currently, there are few projects in my PhpStorm and everyone works well except one. The problem is next: after PhpStorm have stopped on a breakpoint, I can't see any changes when I step over. The system skips variables which I recently added, but it sees "old" vars which were when I made this project.

[image: It looks like this]

Configs in a project are the same as in other projects in PhpStorm.

Comment: What variable you do not see: `$parsed_url` and `$r`. Looks like optimisation from Xdebug end -- those variables are NOT used anywhere later in this function .. so why keeping them.

Comment: Yes, I can not see $parsed_url. Do know how to make optimisation for showing such vars? I keep them for test, previously it worked.

Comment: If Xdebug does not show them ... then you should check possible Xdebug options... Too bad you cannot downgrade to previous Xdebug version to check it since you have PHP 7.2 there.

Comment: Try use Evaluate button -- it may still show what that variable has. Otherwise -- use some useless assignment (e.g. `$aa = $parse_url` -- it may keep such variable for a bit).

Comment: Evaluate button shows `null`. No luck with a useless assignment as well ((

Comment: I realized that $_GLOBALS is changing while I stepping over. Also, I realized, that there are no additional servers in my current project compared with other projects (they "see" each other in every project except current).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added additional permissions (read and write) for the project user group and now Xdebug works better.